# ZXING Android Embedded Usage of IntentIntegrator

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio, zxing

I am new to Android development and still trying to get the grasp of some of the concepts. I find the best way to learn is to jump right into the deep end with a project.  With that said, here is my question:

I have integrated ZXing Android Embedded into my application; however, I am having trouble understanding the way in which you use IntentIntegrator.  All I am trying to do at the moment is call the QR scanner to the screen when the user taps a button.  I have been trying to follow the instructions on their github link [here][1] but have been unsuccessful.

Here is what my function looks like so far:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).initiateScan();

        }

    });
```

I keep getting an error saying:

> Error:(109, 25) error: constructor IntentIntegrator in class
>   IntentIntegrator cannot be applied to given types; required: Activity
>   found: Intent reason: actual argument Intent cannot be converted to
>   Activity by method invocation conversion

Also, as I put my mouse over '(this)' in Android Studio, it says:

> anonymous android.view.View.onClickListener

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!  If you need any other information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

An even easier solution than ChrisStillwell´s would be to make your activity-/fragment-class implement the `OnClickListener`, this way you do not need the reference variable:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Rest of your code

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         if (v.getId == button.getId) {
              IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
              IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).initiateScan();
         }
    }
}
```

If you are implementing a fragment-class, note that you have to call `getActivity()` when creating the `IntentIntegrator`.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing your `OnClickListener` and not your `Fragment` when you say `this` inside your `onClick`. You need to reference your `Fragment`, the easiest way to do that is setup a global variable and call it `myFragment` or something to your liking, then assign it `this`. For example:

```
Fragment myFragment = this;

public void myFunction(){
    // Code and stuff //
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            IntentIntegrator.forFragment(myFragment).initiateScan();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
I ended up restarting my project to at least initiate the scanner upon the app opening. All I did was add copy and paste the one line of code from the github link and pasted it into my onCreate() function.  Also, added the required dependencies.  It ended up working; however, I now face the problem of not having access to the camera.
 It throws up a popup window: "Sorry, the Android camera encountered a problem.  You may need to restart the device."
I added all necessary camera permissions in my Manifest file and configured my AVD accordingly.  I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

following can work:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new IntentIntegrator(getActivity()).initiateScan();
                popupWindow.dismiss();

            }
        });
```