# Issues adding multiple onClick and onActivityResult values on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, printing, bluetooth, zxing

I am trying to build a single page App that scans barcodes with `ZXing` and allows me to then print out `EditText` values on a cheap Bluetooth printer. Then I can clear the `EditText` fields and repeat the process. I have the printing and clearing process working, but I am having trouble adding the `ZXing` parts into the main class. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Disregard the weird symbols that are not displaying I am not having any issues with those. Thanks

Here is my main class:

```
import com.zj.printdemo.R;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.zj.btsdk.BluetoothService;
import com.zj.btsdk.PrintPic;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PrintDemo extends Activity {
    Button btnSearch;
    Button btnSendDraw;
    Button btnSend;
    Button btnClose;
    Button clearBtn;
    Button btnBarcode;
    EditText edtContext;
    EditText edtContextQTY;
    EditText edtPrint;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
    BluetoothService mService = null;
    BluetoothDevice con_dev = null;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;  //��ȡ�豸��Ϣ

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Button clearBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mService = new BluetoothService(this, mHandler);
        //�����������˳�����
        if( mService.isAvailable() == false ){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        clearBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        OnClickListener ClearOnClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edtContext.setText("");
                edtContextQTY.setText("");
            }
        };
        clearBtn.setOnClickListener(ClearOnClickListener);
}


    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //����δ��������
        if( mService.isBTopen() == false)
        {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        try {
            btnSendDraw = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
            btnSendDraw.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
            btnSearch = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
            btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
            btnSend = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
            btnClose = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
            btnClose.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
            edtContext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
            edtContextQTY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_contentQTY);
            btnClose.setEnabled(false);
            btnSend.setEnabled(false);
            btnSendDraw.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("������Ϣ",ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mService != null) 
            mService.stop();
        mService = null; 
    }

    class ClickEvent implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == btnSearch) {           
                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(PrintDemo.this,DeviceListActivity.class);      //��������һ����Ļ
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent,REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
            } else if (v == btnSend) {
                String msg = edtContext.getText().toString();
                String msgQTY = edtContextQTY.getText().toString();
                if( msg.length() > 0 ){
                    mService.sendMessage("ItemID:"+msg+"\n","ItemQTY:"+msgQTY+"\n");
                }
            } else if (v == btnClose) {
                mService.stop();
            } else if (v == btnSendDraw) {
                String msg = "";
                String lang = getString(R.string.strLang);
                //printImage();

                byte[] cmd = new byte[3];
                cmd[0] = 0x1b;
                cmd[1] = 0x21;
                if((lang.compareTo("en")) == 0){    
                    cmd[2] |= 0x10;
                    mService.write(cmd);           //��������ģʽ
                    mService.sendMessage("Congratulations!\n", "GBK"); 
                    cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
                    mService.write(cmd);           //ȡ�����ߡ�����ģʽ
                    msg = "  You have sucessfully created communications between your device and our bluetooth printer.\n\n"
                          +"  the company is a high-tech enterprise which specializes" +
                          " in R&D,manufacturing,marketing of thermal printers and barcode scanners.\n\n";


                    mService.sendMessage(msg,"GBK");
                }else if((lang.compareTo("ch")) == 0){
                    cmd[2] |= 0x10;
                    mService.write(cmd);           //��������ģʽ
                    mService.sendMessage("��ϲ����\n", "GBK"); 
                    cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
                    mService.write(cmd);           //ȡ�����ߡ�����ģʽ
                    msg = "  ���Ѿ��ɹ��������������ǵ�������ӡ����\n\n"
                    + "  ����˾��һ��רҵ�����з�����������������Ʊ�ݴ�ӡ��������ɨ���豸��һ��ĸ߿Ƽ���ҵ.\n\n";

                    mService.sendMessage(msg,"GBK");    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * ����һ��Handlerʵ�������ڽ���BluetoothService�෵�ػ�������Ϣ
     */
    private final  Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case BluetoothService.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED:   //������
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connect successful",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnClose.setEnabled(true);
                    btnSend.setEnabled(true);
                    btnSendDraw.setEnabled(true);
                    break;
                case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTING:  //��������
                    Log.d("��������","��������.....");
                    break;
                case BluetoothService.STATE_LISTEN:     //�������ӵĵ���
                case BluetoothService.STATE_NONE:
                    Log.d("��������","�ȴ�����.....");
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case BluetoothService.MESSAGE_CONNECTION_LOST:    //�����ѶϿ�����
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device connection was lost",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnClose.setEnabled(false);
                btnSend.setEnabled(false);
                btnSendDraw.setEnabled(false);
                break;
            case BluetoothService.MESSAGE_UNABLE_CONNECT:     //�޷������豸
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect device",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:      //���������
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {   //�����Ѿ���
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth open successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {                 //�û������������
                finish();
            }
            break;
        case  REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:     //��������ĳһ�����豸
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {   //�ѵ�������б��е�ĳ���豸��
                String address = data.getExtras()
                                     .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);  //��ȡ�б������豸��mac��ַ
                con_dev = mService.getDevByMac(address);   

                mService.connect(con_dev);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    //��ӡͼ��
    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    private void printImage() {
        byte[] sendData = null;
        PrintPic pg = new PrintPic();
        pg.initCanvas(384);
        pg.initPaint();
        pg.drawImage(0, 0, "/mnt/sdcard/icon.jpg");
        sendData = pg.printDraw();
        mService.write(sendData);   //��ӡbyte������
    }
```

Here is the code I am trying to combine to the above:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnBarcode) {
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            //formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
            contentTxt.setText(scanContent);
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Also, here is my Main layout for the page:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/MainParent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnSearch" >
    </Button>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|top"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:hint="Item ID">

    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/txt_contentQTY"
        android:hint="Item QTY"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnSend" >

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_test" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnClose" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/button_barcode"
        android:id="@+id/btnBarcode" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/button_clear"
        android:id="@+id/btnClear" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Problem**:

When I add the onClick I have to set up a new `OnClickListener` in `OnCreate` and when I do that the `IntenIntegrator` has an issue on (this): `IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);`

Error is the `IntnentIntegrator` cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view,View.OnClickListener)

```
OnClickListener BarcodeOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnBarcode) {
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    }
```

Then I am not sure how to implement the second part. Can I combine the onActivityResult like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data, Intent intent) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:      //���������
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {   //�����Ѿ���
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth open successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {                 //�û������������
                finish();
            }
            break;
        case  REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:     //��������ĳһ�����豸
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {   //�ѵ�������б��е�ĳ���豸��
                String address = data.getExtras()
                                     .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);  //��ȡ�б������豸��mac��ַ
                con_dev = mService.getDevByMac(address);   

                mService.connect(con_dev);
            }
            break;
        }
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            //formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
            edtContext.setText(scanContent);
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

UPDATE 4/14:

With the help posted by @Tung I was able to get the `OnClickListener` issue fixed. I made a few tweaks and got the App to compile and it works.

Here is my updated `OnClickListener`:

```
btnBarcode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBarcode);
    OnClickListener BarcodeOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnBarcode) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(PrintDemo.this);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        }
    };
    btnBarcode.setOnClickListener(BarcodeOnClickListener);
```

New Problem:
I have one slight issue now and I think it has to do with my `onActivityResult`. When I connect the Bluetooth printer and then click the button to scan a barcode it will disconnect my Bluetooth printer. Here is the code I have for my `onActivityResult`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:      //���������
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {   //�����Ѿ���
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth open successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {                 //�û������������
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:     //��������ĳһ�����豸
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {   //�ѵ�������б��е�ĳ���豸��
                    String address = data.getExtras()
                            .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);  //��ȡ�б������豸��mac��ַ
                    con_dev = mService.getDevByMac(address);

                    mService.connect(con_dev);
                }
                break;
        }
            IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (scanningResult != null) {
                String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
                String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
                //formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
                edtContext.setText(scanContent);
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error info added for @Tung D. Nguyen

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen I see that you are very experienced on this subject and this site. Is there anything else I can add to my question to make it more clear so that someone might be able to help me? Also, thanks for helping me reword my question earlier.

Comment: What was the result? e.g. requestCode? You should give more detail or open a new question for this part.

Comment: @Tung There is not more detail that I can give, it works it just makes me reconnect the printer after the barcode scan. I am not sure what else to add. I don't think the way I created the onActivityResult is right. Look at the IntentResult section, should there be another case or switch or how should this be handled?

Comment: At least, you can make sure that `onActivityResult` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question may contain more sub-questions. That is why people hard to tell what exactly action to help.

I will try to clarify the first point from your code.

```
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
```

`this` causes the error of

> anonymous android.view,View.OnClickListener

To fix this, your must replace `this` with a suitable parameter (I think it should be a Fragment/Activity based on my search of it constructor on [GitHub](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java)). So it should be (replace `PrintDemo.this` with some activity contains the code):

```
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(PrintDemo.this);
```

Try it and update your question.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852754/zxing-android-embedded-usage-of-intentintegrator)

Comment: I will be back on the project Thursday and will try to implement this fix then report back here. Thanks

Comment: I made some progress with your help and updated the question with a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand problem exactly, there is answer about start zxing scanning from button. But in my app I have bluetooth with zxing scanner together, if you clarify you problem, I'll help. So:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFind"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Find QR">
```

In MainActivity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        integrator.initiateScan();
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the most basic term I am try to combine code snippet 2 in my question to code snippet 1. Right now I can do one or the other independently, but when combined I get the problems I listed.